# You almost got yourself killed, Is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

> You almost got yourself killed.
>   You almost got killed yourself.
>   You almost got yourself to kill.
>   or ...

Comment: All three are correct, but all mean very different things. Without context, we cannot know which sense is intended.

Comment: How is that possible!!!! Plz give me more information about them. I was watching Terminator 2 movie then confront with it. obviously, the first one is correct in my situation but I want to learn more.

Comment: If you want to learn more, you should ask a more specific question. You might read through [this meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) along with its answers for more hints.

Comment: "me too" :)  I am especially interested in understanding sentence 2. I have no problem with the others.

Answer (score 3):

1) You almost got **yourself** killed. [emphatic]

get oneself [killed, kicked out of class, framed, in trouble, run over] get + past participle or phrase here means: to find oneself in a situation where something is done to you.

2) You almost got killed yourself. [this implies others **were** killed]

- He almost got in trouble himself. [others did get in trouble]This emphasizes that he did not but others did.

3)You almost got yourself to kill.

Ok, well, this one is a bit iffy. It can mean: you almost convinced yourself to kill.

to get yourself to do something.

Usually, you get others to do something.

Comment: Would you just tell me which part of the sentence implies others were killed? I am a bit confused about the second one! I have never encountered such sentences before!

Comment: The second one could also be used as a "rebuttal" of sorts: "Watch out! You almost got killed!" "You're telling me that? You almost got killed yourself."

Answer (score -2):

I believe the meaning that you are looking for is conveyed by the first expression.
That is the expression used:

get + somebody + past participle

It means you were just about to kill yourself, or you put yourself in a situation that was leading to your death.

The others are also correct, but they have different meanings. The second one means you yourself were about to be killed. The third one means you almost forced or persuaded yourself to kill (somebody).

Comment: I can't understand. Would you refer me to grammar

Comment: The grammar is what I told you. You can take a look at the 18th sense at [the LDOCE entrance for "get"](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get).

Comment: No, all three are correct, but the meanings are different.

Comment: @Diamond: "refer me to grammar" means - please provide one or more links where the issue is described with more details. This is actually the rule of posting answers here on ELL.